# Create simple HTTP proxy server which replies fake contents, Java

Tags: java, proxy

I am trying to create a simple proxy server(very simple, doesn't even cache everything) that swaps contents(words, Images, and href) from the reply of origin and forward back to the client. (A proxy server that sends "Fake News" to the client).

I can change every occurrence of "Cat" into "Dog" and every occurrence of "Moon" to "Sun", but I don't know how to swaps the images and hrefs.

Thank you!

```
public class GetHttp {

    public static String extractHost(String request) {
        String[] tokens = request.split("\n");
        String url = tokens[1].split(" ")[1];
        return url;
    }

    public static byte[] replaceContext(byte[] message) {
        String toReturn = new String(message);

// Here is the problem: I don't know how to swap href and images.
        //toReturn = toReturn.replaceAll("<img src=\"This is a place holder\"","<img src=\"This is a place holder\" width");
        //toReturn = toReturn.replaceAll("<a href=\"This is a place Holder\">", "<a href=\"This is a place Holder\">");

        toReturn = toReturn.replaceAll("Cat", "Dog");
        toReturn = toReturn.replaceAll("Moon", "Sun");
        System.out.println(toReturn);
   );

        return toReturn.getBytes();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8888);

        while (true) {
            Socket connectionSocket = server.accept();
            BufferedInputStream inFromClient = new BufferedInputStream(connectionSocket.getInputStream());

            // Server reads the HTTP request 
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            inFromClient.read(buffer);
            String clientRequest = new String(buffer);
            String originName = extractHost(clientRequest);

            // Create the http request from server to the origin
            Socket origin = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(originName.trim()), 80);
            BufferedOutputStream outToOrigin = new BufferedOutputStream(origin.getOutputStream());
            outToOrigin.write(clientRequest.getBytes());
            outToOrigin.flush();

            // receive the content from origin
            // return back to the client
            BufferedInputStream inFromOrigin = new BufferedInputStream(origin.getInputStream());

            buffer = new byte[8192];
            int buffersize = 0;
            BufferedOutputStream outToClient = new BufferedOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
            
            
            while ((buffersize=inFromOrigin.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                byte[] temp = new byte[buffersize];
                for(int i=0;i<buffersize;i++){
                    temp[i] = buffer[i];
                }
                // swap the context
                outToClient.write(replaceContext(temp));// ,0,buffsize);
            }

            outToClient.flush();
            outToOrigin.close();
            inFromOrigin.close();
            inFromClient.close();
            outToClient.close();
            origin.close();
            connectionSocket.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: While I'm having a really bad premonition about your intentions; if you want to swap images, base64 encoding might be the easiest thing to do.

Comment: I would like to swap the images in the HTTP reply from origin to server with another image from URL(like, some url /cat.jpg)

Comment: Well, you'll have to do some parsing of the HTML for this to isolate the `href` attribute from `a` or `img` tags. And for that, you have a dozen of choices out there. Whereas the "easiest" method might be just to use indexOf, substring and replace.

Comment: I will try, thank you.